# I received a max limit on Geocoding address using MMQGIS when choosing OSM/Nominatim

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim, mmqgis

I was trying to run a geocode process (~20,000 addresses) using MMQGIS and the OSM/Nominatim web service.

[image]

On the first run I input my CSV file and designated all parameters. However, I hit a max limit error for Google API.

[image]

Even though, I didn't choose Google API and my understanding of OSM/Nominatim  there are no limit to geocoding addresses.

When I tried to rerun the geocode service thinking it was a false error I got this.

[image]

I've tried searching for responses that may provide some insight, however I have been unsuccessful in finding anything useful. As far as I can tell, there should be no limit on the OSM and for Google is 2,500 which is fine, I'm not trying to use Google Map API web service.

Why am I receiving this error now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking at my installed copy of the plugin (latest plugin version, 2017.5.14) there's an error message which reports that it couldn't connect to google API even if it's actually using Nominatim, so this might actually be an error from Nominatim.

There are [limits and usage policies in place for Nominatim](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/) so it's possible that the plugin has been given a limited per-app quota.

That page suggest max 1 query/sec, this plugin currently rate-limits to 2 query/sec, so that might explain the 429?

Comment: Where do you see that the plugin rate -limits is 2 query/sec?

Comment: there's a `sleep(0.5)` inside the loop which sends each feature to the API; that's a typical technique for slowing down a loop to (approximately) 2 times a second

Comment: Would it be possible to alter that to satisfy the 1 query/sec and then let it run ?

Comment: that *might* work, sleep(2.0) would slow it down. I don't have any test data to try it out on, though. Might be worth raising an issue with the plugin author (there are other services, like MapZen's, which need an API key like Google, which are maybe more suitable for bulk usage)

Comment: Even more suitable for bulk usage is to set up your own Nominatim instance for a virtually unlimited number of requests.

Comment: very good point @mmd, installing Nominatim or Pelias would be worth looking at for such a large run. Could you expand this into an answer?

Comment: The easiest way to get a Nominatim instance (of sorts) up and running is to use Photon with the pre-compiled search index: https://github.com/komoot/photon